# "No module named pefile" even though I have installed pefile

Tags: python

I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.8 on the same computer

I am trying to get this to work: https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker

The requirements are:

```
pefile==2017.9.3
unpy2exe==0.3
uncompyle6==2.11.5
xdis==3.5.5
pycrypto==2.6.1
configparser==3.5.0
```

And I guess the other stuff is installed correctly (not sure). But when I try to currently run this thing with `python python_exe_unpack.py -i [programname.exe]`

I get the error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named pefile
```

I've run both of these commands:

```
py -m pip install pefile==2017.9.3

py -m pip install pefile==2019.4.18
```

and the problem persists.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: `python` and `py` are probably not linked to the same executable. Use the same one for all commands.

Comment: It's likely that `py` on your path goes to Python 3, so when you run the script with Python 2 it can't find the module as the module was installed for Python 3. In Command Prompt try typing `where py`, that should give the path of the program associated with `py`, if that path is for Python 3 then you either need to run the script you download in Python 3 or specify it's Python 2 you want to use for pip e.g `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install pefile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `pip freeze` to obtain the list of installed packages. Probably your `py` and `python` executables aren't the same, try `py python_exe_unpack.py -i [programname.exe]`. Also check which paths you using to obtain that package:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You can add extra paths through `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or just `sys.path.append("/path/to/folder")` with path where is you're installed pefile.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!!